# Как удалит обьект в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Моя программа проверяет логин и пароль, и выводит текст с удачной или неудачной попыткой в виде виджета. И при нажатии на кнопку, виджет накладывается на другой. Как сделать так, чтобы виджет удалялся, и на место его была выведена следующая попытка?

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry(f'400x500')
win.title('Мое приложение')

password = '123'
login = 'Aleks'

def get_entry():
    global password, login
    val1 = password_get.get()
    val2 = login_get.get()
    if val1 == password and val2 == login:
        l = tk.Label(win, text='Вы успешно вошли!').grid(row=3, column=1)
    else:
        k = tk.Label(win, text='Неверный логин или пароль!').grid(row=3, column=1)

def delet1():
    password_get.delete(0, tk.END)
def delet2():
    login_get.delete(0, tk.END)

lbl = tk.Label(win, text='Пароль').grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl2 = tk.Label(win, text='Логин').grid(row=1, column=0)

password_get = tk.Entry(win)
password_get.grid(row=0, column=1)

login_get = tk.Entry(win)
login_get.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn = tk.Button(win, text='get', command=get_entry).grid(row=2, column=1)
btn2 = tk.Button(win, text='del', command=delet1).grid(row=0, column=2)
btn3 = tk.Button(win, text='del', command=delet2).grid(row=1, column=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Не ругайте за говнокод) Пока только учусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способов несколько...

1. Запоминать ссылку на `Label` и каждый раз удалять предыдущую при помощи метода `destroy()` и пересоздавать заново:

```
...
status_label = None  # для запоминания ссылки на виджет

def get_entry():
    global password, login, status_label
    val1 = password_get.get()
    val2 = login_get.get()
    if status_label:
        status_label.destroy()  # уничтожаем старый виджет 
    if val1 == password and val2 == login:
        status_label = tk.Label(win, text='Вы успешно вошли!')
    else:
        status_label = tk.Label(win, text='Неверный логин или пароль!')
    status_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
...
```

2. `Label` создать один раз и потом менять в ней текст при помощи метода `configure()`:

```
...
def get_entry():
    global password, login
    val1 = password_get.get()
    val2 = login_get.get()
    if val1 == password and val2 == login:
        status_label.configure(text='Вы успешно вошли!')
    else:
        status_label.configure(text='Неверный логин или пароль!')
...
lbl = tk.Label(win, text='Пароль').grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl2 = tk.Label(win, text='Логин').grid(row=1, column=0)
status_label = tk.Label(win)
status_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
...
```

3. Создать `Label` единожды и указать ей параметр `textvariable` со ссылкой на переменную. Тогда при изменении этой переменной текст будет автоматически отображён в `Label`:

```
...
status = tk.StringVar() # переменная с содержимым для Label

def get_entry():
    global password, login
    val1 = password_get.get()
    val2 = login_get.get()
    if val1 == password and val2 == login:
        status.set('Вы успешно вошли!')
    else:
        status.set('Неверный логин или пароль!')
...
lbl = tk.Label(win, text='Пароль').grid(row=0, column=0)
lbl2 = tk.Label(win, text='Логин').grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(win, textvariable=status).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)
...
```